# Jquery 3 select with condition by index to show or display content

Tags: jquery

I have a list select in the need find by index and the get value. of first 3 select by index().
if 1 or 3 index have value >= 34 will show the  text if not will hiden. pls review my image will understand more

It is not working well , please review file image attachment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HncUr.jpg)

```js
//index , of first 3 select tag
var index = $(this).index();

var list_arr = [0, 1, 2];

var is_exits = $.inArray(index, list_arr);

if (fabric_value != null) {
  if (fabric_value >= 34 && is_exits == 0 || is_exits == 1 || is_exits == 2) {
    $(".extra_fabric_10dollar").show();
  } else {
    $(".extra_fabric_10dollar").hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>34</option>
  <option>78</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>34</option>
  <option>55</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>15</option>
  <option>34</option>
  <option>88</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>33</option>
</select>
<span>I am show when select by index meet 0 - 1 - 2 has value larger 34 if less than will hide</span>
```

Comment: What is `this` referring to in your code? Did you include all relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: none of your elements have any class name assigned. You were trying to show or hide `.extra_fabric_10dollar` elements. You have to add it to the `<span>` for jQuery to actually select the element of your choice:

```
<span class="extra_fabric_10dollar">I am show when select by index meet 0 - 1 - 2 has value larger 34 if less than will hide</span>
```

Once you did this, use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    var showNotification = $(this).val() >= 34;
    $(".extra_fabric_10dollar").toggle(showNotification);
  });
});
```

This code toggles the desired classes element on or off based on the `.val() >= 34` of the changed `<select>`. Since your question didn't make it clear whether these values are fixed or variable, I made the jQuery selector match **all** `<select>`s. If you want to only match the first 3 `<select>`s, use `$('select:nth-child(-n+3)').on('change',` instead.

If you want to hide the span by default upon start, add the following CSS:

```
.extra_fabric_10dollar {
  display: none;
}
```

It will then only show up on selecting a value greater or equal 34.

Comment: Did you check the image in my question?.

have some case need show or hiden <span> tag.

If 1 or 3 select have big than 34 will show span tag. but your code not have this.